# How to SELECT Distinct Count from SELECT with Union All SELECT

Tags: t-sql

I need to get a count from a query with UNION ALL, but all my attempts so far have failed and I cannot get it to work.

My Initial SELECT (Which returns 8 unique departments)

```
select distinct Department 
from ( select Department
       from EFP_EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit
       union all
       select Department from EFP_EmploymentUser ) 
a order by Department;
```

I have tried different variations of the following

```
SELECT COUNT(Department) as "DepCount"
FROM ( select Department
       from EFP_EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit
       union all
       select Department
       from EFP_EmploymentUser );
```

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE!**

I finally got it to work .. thank you to all :-)

The final query:

```
    select count(*) from (
    select distinct Department 
    from ( 
        select Department 
        from EFP_EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit 
        union all 
        select Department 
        from EFP_EmploymentUser ) as ddep) as depcount;
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Department) ...`

Comment: Why use `union all` when `union` will remove duplicate values?

Comment: agreed with Bill, can probably just use union instead of union all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query, it should work:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct Department 
    from ( select Department from EFP_EmployeeFollowupManagerCommit 
    union all 
    select Department from EFP_EmploymentUser ));
```

Comment: @jihendra thenuwara .. unfortunately it throughs the error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 ncorrect syntax near ')'`

Comment: That's because the inline views are not aliased.  Needs to be written as
`select ... from (query) as SomeName`

Comment: @StigKølbæk is there any way you can setup a sandbox where we can run queries against this table to test the query out

Comment: @Jithendra Thenuwara : I have setup SQL Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88944/2

Comment: @Jithendra Thenuwara :  I got it working .(See my updated post) .. thank you for the help,  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this:
select count(distinct Department)

Comment: unfortunately I cannot get that to work eigther (also see my comment to jithendra thenuwara)